# How to hide roles from user_profil_form while keeping value?

Tags: 7, users

After loading user_profil_form form, I tried to hide the roles fields.
It worked fine, however after submitting the form, my user roles are removed and it's only linked to "authenticated user".

Is there a way hide this field but keeping the value ? I would not like to user the alter hook in order to keep the full form in the admin pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, unsetting the field works fine to disallow access to a field while keeping values on update. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    unset($form['account']['roles']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not want this to affect the admin pages so I am trying to avoid using hook_form_alter.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by "admin" pages but the if statement in the above code means that it will work on the user/add page and user/[uid]/edit page. If you don't want to hide this field for admins then you will need to apply that condition in your code. Preferably by writing your own custom permission through hook_permission and calling user_access with your permission as an argument.

Comment: Thank you, you're right using permissions and your code is the perfect answer in that case !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the '[#access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access)' = 0 for the roles field appropriately to hide it from users

Comment: I thought so, however while logged with the administrator :
account '#access' = 0 hide the field and while saving, the roles are removed and "authenticated user" is the only one left